# Is there a way to detect if browser is ran as an administrator?

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome

The question is like in the title: is there a way to programmatically detect if a browser instance is elevated or no?

Short story: i've built a very simple drag and drop interface which worked fine, but some users said that they're unable to use DnD and they couldn't explain why: when file dragged, Chrome just rendered mouse cursor a "not allowed" sign and didn't trigger any JS events.

I [found out](https://superuser.com/questions/994283/google-chromes-drag-drop-feature-stopped-working/995020#995020) that this happens when Chrome is ran as an administrator. If i can do nothing about it to pass through this mechanism, i'd at least like to inform users that it's just a Chrome restriction, not a page error.

Thanks in advance!

*PS: please, translate the question and the title to proper english, thanks*

Comment: To be precise, it happens when Windows Explorer and Chrome do not run under the same credentials. Having an elevated Chrome instance together with a non-elevated Explorer instance is just one of the possible cases.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, i just tested it, and for me Chrome prohibits file drag and drop only if a browser instance is elevated, no matter if explorer elevated or no